# Update Table From Select Inner Join With No Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table with values from a join. However, running this gives me 0 rows updated. When replacing the update statement with a select I get the 1 row join.

The below is just something I'm trying to achieve at work. Get the child policy ID $amount that's related to the next policy (they are not related and depends on the dates. They are linked via the rgnID)and update a temp table. I modified the below just to simulate.

```sql
create table tTB1 (plcyID int, rgnID int, ncptdt datetime, plctypID int)

insert into tTB1 (plcyID , rgnID , ncptdt , plctypID)
values (1,1,'2017-10-01',1),(2,1,'2018-10-01',2),
(3,1,'2018-10-01',3),(4,1,'2019-10-01',2)

--create table #tTEMP (total int, plcyID int, rgnID int, ncptdt datetime, plctypID int)
--select * from tTB1
;WITH cteLYPolicy
AS
(
select p.rgnID,MXPLCY=MAX(p.plcyID)
  FROM tTB1 t
  INNER JOIN tTB1 p ON p.rgnID=t.rgnID and p.ncptdt<t.ncptdt and p.plcyID<t.plcyID and p.plctypID in (1,2)
  WHERE t.plctypID=2
  GROUP BY p.rgnID
)
--UPDATE l
--set l.plctypID = 10--p.plctypID
select * 
from cteLYPolicy cte
inner join tTB1 l ON l.plcyID =cte.MXPLCY --ly
inner join tTB1 p ON p.rgnID=l.rgnID and p.ncptdt>l.ncptdt and p.ncptdt = DATEADD(year,1,l.ncptdt)
```

Comment: As a first step, I would reorder the final update, so the table `tTB1` is in the from clause. It's not the problem here, but it is confusing as sin.

Comment: @Camus . . . How are you determining the rows updated?  The best method is to use `OUTPUT`.  then you can use `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: @gordonlinoff this is determined by the ‘filters’ on the joins. They work similarly in this case as where caluse

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server, and most RDMS's for that matter, will behave this way if the value of the column is already the value you're attempting to set.

Demo of this behaviour: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8eb54/7

```sql
CREATE TABLE [t] (
  PRIMARY KEY ([n])
  , [n] INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [t] ([n])
SELECT 1;
-- 0 Rows affected 

UPDATE [t]
SET [n] = 1
WHERE 1 = 1;
-- 0 Rows affected 

SELECT * FROM [t];
-- 1 Row returned
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get it. Even if is do something similar to l.plctypID = 10 and then do a select after the update, I'm not getting anything.

Comment: When you select, what is the value of `plctypID`?

Comment: I edited my cte. When I do a select I get 1 row with all the joined table.
When I try to update to any value I get o rows affected. Am I missing anything?